# In html5 how do I ensure item below two images always centred

Tags: css, html

So I have a text of paragraph alongside an image, for a default computer screen I ideally want the size of the height of the image to prevent the text wrapping under it so I sometimes adjust the jpeg so that is has greater space around it.

And then sometimes I have an embedded video that I want to center as I show in the screenshot.
[image: How I want things]

The trouble if there is not enough text then if I embed a video its only centred on the width of the above text rather than the whole screen, as shown in [image: here]

If there is too much text so its flow undetr the image then things continue to work okay, the problem is when this is not enough. The difficulty is that no perfect setting for image/text since it will change as the screen changes and also for translated pages the length of the translated text will vary and I dont want to modify the image border for each language. The problem I have is I always want the video to be centered regardless how can I ensure this.

This is example html

```
<div class="Section">
<img src="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/images/classical.png" class="section_image align_left"/>
<h2>Understands Classical</h2>
<p>SongKong understands Classical music. The Metadata demands for Classical are very different to Pop/Rock music, credit is usually given to not only the performer but also the
conductor, orchestra and composer. In Pop/Rock an album usually represents the artistic intent of the artist, i.e. the album was conceived
and created as a single body of work. In Classical it is more complicated, Classical composers work in terms of Symphonies or Sonatas
rather than albums, we call these Works. These works comprise sub works or movements, and there may be additional levels. When Classical music is released as an album it may only contain part of a
work, or conversely multiple works, so the album grouping may not be the most important grouping.
SongKong identifies Classical releases and captures this additional information in dedicated metadata fields.
It can also identify other Classical information such as the Opus No and the performers with their instruments. SongKong can automtically update the new iTunes Work and Movement fields.
</p>
<div class="videowrapper">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6Es-eaG4xPg" name="Classical and iTunes" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
 .section_image {
        height: auto;
    }
    .Section {
            clear:both;
            padding-top:50px;
            padding-bottom:50px;
    }

    .align_left {
        float:left;
        margin-right:20px;
        clear:both;
    }

    .align_right {
        float:right;
        margin-left:20px;
        clear:both;
    }

  .videowrapper iframe {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display:table;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
    }
```

Comment: use `.videowrapper{text-align:center; width: 100%}` and `iframe{display:; inline-block}` on the video iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="Section">
<img src="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/images/classical.png" class="section_image align_left"/>
<h2>Understands Classical</h2>
<p>SongKong understands Classical music. The Metadata demands for Classical are very different to Pop/Rock music, credit is usually given to not only the performer but also the
conductor, orchestra and composer. In Pop/Rock an album usually represents the artistic intent of the artist, i.e. the album was conceived
and created as a single body of work. In Classical it is more complicated, Classical composers work in terms of Symphonies or Sonatas
rather than albums, we call these Works. These works comprise sub works or movements, and there may be additional levels. When Classical music is released as an album it may only contain part of a
work, or conversely multiple works, so the album grouping may not be the most important grouping.
SongKong identifies Classical releases and captures this additional information in dedicated metadata fields.
It can also identify other Classical information such as the Opus No and the performers with their instruments. SongKong can automtically update the new iTunes Work and Movement fields.
</p>
<div class="clear-fix"></div>
<div class="videowrapper">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6Es-eaG4xPg" name="Classical and iTunes" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>


.section_image {
        height: auto;
    }
    .Section {
            clear:both;
            padding-top:50px;
            padding-bottom:50px;
    }

    .align_left {
        float:left;
        margin-right:20px;
        clear:both;
    }

    .align_right {
        float:right;
        margin-left:20px;
        clear:both;
    }

  .videowrapper iframe {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display:table;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .clear-fix {
      clear: both;
    }
```

Live example https://jsfiddle.net/h26quu5f/

Comment: A good answer need an explanation what's been done to solve the issue

Comment: @grinmax thanks I tried your jsfiddle and deleted some text so shorter than image height and it worked perfectly, however making the change on my actual code has not worked I cannot see whats different http://www.jthink.net/songkong/index.jsp - (look at the Making Your Mind Up section) , any idea please ?

Comment: @LGSon I couldnt get this working on my site, any idea why please

Comment: @PaulTaylor Then try my solution ... very simple, just add the textwrapper and the clearfix rule attached to it

Comment: @PaulTaylor you have wrong css property https://yadi.sk/d/rVt1Ewse3At5an

Comment: @grinmax I didnt notice the extra clear-fix div required but in my css i just added  .videowrapper {clear: both;} which hasd worked and meant I didnt have to modify all my html, thanks.